# VS2015 - DLL Manifest visibility in Description pane of Object Browser

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, manifest, objectbrowser

I am creating a few WPF Custom Controls in VS2015 (C#) which I would like to distribute to a Shared library for other Development Team members. In order for these folks to reference the namespaces in these DLLs the preferred manner would be to use a xmlns:prefix with a URI rather than the clr-namespace syntax. I have set (in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the Custom Control) the

[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.DPACMediaSystem.com/CustomControls/", "DPACCustomControl0012.Controls")]

The developers actually use the URI and everything works ok..BUT..

I would like them to be able to see this URI in the Object Browser in the Description pane of the particular DLL.

Simple question, eventhough I can see that it exists in the manifest of the DLL through ildasm.exe, is there some setting on building the DLL that I must set to make this visible in the Object Browser ?

Any help appreciated..

Cheers,

Dezzz.